# Getting moved files to inherit permissions in Linux

Tags: files, permissions, acl

I have set up a folder that is assigned to a group.

```
drwxrws---+   2 operator    IDGroup    4096 Jul 21 10:22 MyTest
```

The following ACL is applied:

```
setfacl -Rdm group:IDGroup:rw MyTest
```

Files **created** in this directory inherit group IDGroup which is correct.

Files **moved** into this directory retain their original group ownership which is what I do not want.

Is there a way to have files moved into this directory get reassigned to group IDGroup?

Comment: I wrote a script using inotifywait that watches for a file created or moved into that directory or below and runs a chmod and chgrp on the file. It's a hack but it works.

Comment: pls post your script